# Create Navigation bar using Mixin in Jade

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I want to create a nav bar like this by mixin:

```
<ul class="pets">
    <li><a(class="cat",href="a")>cat</a></li>
    <li><a(class="dog",href="a")>dog</a></li>
    <li><a(class="pig",href="a")>pig</a></li>
</ul>
```

I try to write this but it was not correctly:

```
mixin pets(pets,links)
  ul.pets
    - each pet,p in pets,links
      - var f = '<a(class="'+pet+'",href="'+p+'")>'
      li!= f + pet+'</a>'
+pets(['cat', 'dog', 'pig'],['a','a','a'])
```

and this is result:

```
<ul class="pets">
    <li><a(class="cat",href="0")>cat</a></li>
    <li><a(class="dog",href="1")>dog</a></li>
    <li><a(class="pig",href="2")>pig</a></li>
</ul>
```

I don't know how to do that, please help me...:( 
thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are renderig `p`(which is the index of pets array in each iteration) to the output. Instead of doing so you can simply render the `pth` element of links array in each iteration.

```
mixin pets(pets, links)
   ul.pets
     - each pet,p in pets
       - var f = '<a (class="'+pet + '", href="'+ links[p] +'")>'
       li!= f + pet + '</a>'

+pets(['cat','dog','pig'],['a','a','a'])
```